# Is there method to get referral code from google play store in android?

Tags: java, android, google-play, referrals

if userA share his link referral with  userB .when userB download app and do some function  then app send referral id for userA to backend to increase points for userA

Is it possible to see that referrer (if any) in the code of my app?

i have tried used Play Install Referrer Library
but returned referrer string is 
utm_source=(not%20set)&utm_medium=(not%20set)
for referral link https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sfn.android&referrer=9BE46550

then try using BroadcastReceiver
for example:

```
public class InstallReferrerReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static String TAG = "InstallReferrerReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String referrer = intent.getStringExtra("referrer");

        //Use the referrer
        Log.d(TAG, "onReceive:InstallReferrerReceiver " + referrer);
    }
}
```

in androidManifest.xml:

```
    <application>
     <receiver
            android:name="com.gosnash.android.utils.InstallReferrerReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
```

but not work also

Comment: Follow the app sharing/app invite guide. The application gets the share url when launched after an successful invite install. Query the url for the referrer parameter and you will get it.

Comment: Have a look at firebase dynamic links , https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/android/receive

Comment: @RahulShukla can you share code or link to me to implement what you say

Comment: Hi, I'm looking for this solution too. Did you able to accomplish it without using firebase and/or branch.io? I would like to make it without 3rd party systems.

Comment: @Kostanos i success implement it using firebase dynamic links and i don't know if you can implement it without third party libs